# unabe to get static css files at express.js

Tags: node.js

i am trying by first express web app and I am using ejs template to render my web page and css to style my pages.
but server is unable to render css file from public folder. i put the static file path at express .js as follow

```
    express = require('express'),
        var app = express();
```

i tried to put static file path to express.js

```
 // app.use(express.static('../public')); 
    app.use("/public",express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
   // app.use(express.static('../../public'));  //./
   // app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    //app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../../public'));
```

and gave link to to my signup.ejs page

```
 <link href="/public/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

my directory structure as follow

```
app
|-view
     |- signup.ejs 


public
|-mystyle.css

express.js
```

When i started my server its give me 404 not found error. although my localhost is working good only problem is my web page is unable to get css file in webpage

Comment: You should call `app.use` before `app.listen`

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin that's not necessary at all.

Comment: I suggest you try `app.use("/public",express.static(__dirname + './public'));`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the port you have entered in the app.listen() is correct?
try

```
app.listen(port no., 'your localhost', function() {
  console.log("... port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

Comment: yes all port cofig is done and it working properly  only problem to in render css file to webpage

Comment: perhaps you have written mystyless in your public folder and you are writing mystyle.css in your link

Comment: sorry for that mistake  thats writing mistake

Comment: Set the view engine to ejs by the following code  app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); and then // use res.render to load up an ejs view file

Answer (score 0):

Change the following two things:

1. Make link relative: `app.use("/public",express.static(__dirname + './public'));`
2. No need of navigating to /public again, since express.js already searches for static files in this folder: `<link href="/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

See: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: thnx man.... I found this early but thnx for your support your answer is 100% correct